# GitLab 7.8 Email Notifications not working

Tags: email, notifications, sendmail, gitlab, gitlab-7

I just installed GitLab 7.8 CE and all email notifications are not working. (Register/ForgotPassword/ResendConfirmation/ChangeEmail and many more)

After ~6 hours i'm just clueless how to solve this problem. Pls help!

It has something todo with "sendmail". But i have no clue how to switch it to "postfix" for example. The Server is CentOS7. I also searched all different kind of logs, but there is not a single response in any file. So no debugging either ;(

/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml

```
email_enabled: true
email_from: user@provider.com
```

/gitlab/config/environments/production.yml

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :stmp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
  location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
  arguments: '-i'
}

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'provider.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'my-domain.com',
  user_name:            'user@provider.com',
  password:             'password',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`delivery_method` can either be `:smtp` or `:sendmail` (also, `:test` and `:file`, which are likely irrelevant for you). If you're using `:smtp`, then you don't need the `sendmail_settings` section, but you do need to properly configure the `smtp_settings` section.

In 7.8, I think smtp settings should go in config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb (see example file [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/7-8-stable/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb.sample)).

See this link for all of the ActionMailer configuration options:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html